# httr how to set up a PUT request that requires and object as per an API

Tags: r, put, httr, jsonlite

I want to send a PUT request via a certain platform API and am struggling in setting this up correctly because the PUT request requires on "object".

The specific PUT request is this one: https://release.decipherinc.com/s/local/api.html#survey-metadata-quota-limits-put

I tried the following:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

decipher_key <- "MYKEY"

my_args <- list(limits = unbox("'/Gender/au':'1600'"))

body <- toJSON(my_args)

put_request <- PUT(url = "https://MYSURVEY/quota/edit",
                 add_headers('x-apikey' = decipher_key),
                 content_type("application/json"),
                 body = body,
                 encode = "json")
```

This gives the following error:

```
$`$error`
[1] "argument 'limits': object expected, not 'str'"

$`$code`
[1] 400

$extra
NULL
```

I guess my code above encodes the request as a string and not as the required object. However, I've no idea how I should setup such an "object". Any ideas?

(When I get rid of the "unbox" part in my code, I get a similar error telling me that my "limits" argument is coded as a list, not an object.)

Comment: Try `my_args <- list(limits = list("/Gender/au" = unbox("1600")))`

Comment: Great. This works nicely. Out of curiosity: is there any tutorial or documentation on how to encode the different inputs so that they match the APIs requirements?

Comment: No. Every API is different. It all depends on how well it’s documented. But in general it’s best not to try to build your own JSON with strings. Let jsonlite do it for you with proper list objects.

Comment: OK, thanks. So I guess the way you described above is what you would recommend? So far all my requests to that API contain some form of list in the `my_args` object, so I hope this is what hopefully works in most cases.